# Google / Mapbox static maps displaying custom image with certain bounds

Tags: javascript, mapbox, google-maps-api, overlay

I have a process which generates a simple Google Static Map (can also be a MapBox static image as the code is pretty much interchangeable).

It's recycled code from a project I found years ago.

The final map url creation string is something like this:

```
var mapurl = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=" +
            center[1].toFixed(6) + "," + center[0].toFixed(6) +
            "&zoom=" + zoominfo.zoom + "&size=" + mapsize.width + "x" + mapsize.height + "&scale=4&format=png&key=APIKEY" + mapStyle
```

Lets say a URL string is this:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=42.803331,4.744135&zoom=7&size=640x640&scale=4&format=png&key=APIKEY&maptype=hybrid
```

And produces this map:
[image: Map]

What I'd like to do is set up a bounding box for a specific set of lat/lon co-oridnates, and if the the url generated comes within those bounds, a seperate "customised" image is instead shown as an overlay.  Think of this as essentially a custom map tile, nothing to do with google or mapbox static maps.

This map tile represents a particular region on earth, aligned to specific co-ordinates.

The end result would be something like this:
[image: Map with custom overlay]

The closest thing I've seen is an implementaion of Google Maps GL JS where an overlay can be added: https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/image-on-a-map/

This is essentially what I'm trying to do, albeit with Static Maps.  Static Maps does not allow you to add custom raster overlays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using Mapbox you could create a [custom style](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/tutorials/create-a-custom-style/) within your account which combines the base satellite map with your overlay image into a single style, then use that style with [Mapbox Static Images API](https://docs.mapbox.com/api/maps/#static-images).

Comment: Thanks @AndrewHarvey - I've played around with custom styles in MBStudio but didn't realise I could incorporate a staic image overlay into it.  I can see an option for SVG sprites/glyphs (road sign styles and so on).  Is there documentation on how to overlay a JPG/PNG?

Comment: See https://docs.mapbox.com/help/tutorials/georeferencing-imagery/ for how to georeference and upload raster data you can then use in Mapbox Studio.